# Download PDF from admin using PHP MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, admin, require-once

I have an admin manager where i can export user details in an EXCEL format as well as two different pdfs (all this connected through MySql).

I've moved the admin site to a different domain where everything is the same but the information of the visa,extra pdfs,excel sections are now one subfolder up. So it's no longer the **domain/admin/event/folder** but **domain/admin/REGISTRATION/event/folder** THE ONLY thing that doesn't work is the download part. The following code is where i think the trouble starts

```
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/login_check.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../inc/funciones.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../connections/conexion.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../connections/conexion_event.php');

if($_GET['accion'] == "visa") {
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT e.Id, e.folder FROM events e WHERE e.Id = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt -> execute(array($_SESSION['sid_event']));
        $event = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $id_user  = $_GET['id'];
        $download = true;
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $event->folder . '/inc/visa_pdf.php');
    }
}

if($_GET['accion'] == "extra") {
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT e.Id, e.folder FROM events e WHERE e.Id = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt -> execute(array($_SESSION['sid_event']));
        $event = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $id_user  = $_GET['id'];
        $id_extra = $_GET['id_extra'];
        $download = true;
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $event->folder . '/inc/extra_pdf.php');
    }
}

if($_GET['accion'] == "excel") {
    $stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT e.Id, e.folder FROM events e WHERE e.Id = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt -> execute(array($_SESSION['sid_event']));
    $event = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $event->folder . '/vendor/autoload.php'); // dependency (compose)

    $stmt = $db_event -> prepare("SELECT u.*, c.name as country, c.mu FROM users u INNER JOIN countries c ON c.Id = u.id_country WHERE u.active = 1 ORDER BY u.Id ASC");
    $stmt -> execute();
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

now to access the new subfolder i've tried `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../registration' . $event->folder . '/vendor/autoload.php');` 
and 
`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $event->folder . 'registration/vendor/autoload.php');`

but i can't get the file to download. If someone can point me in the right direction it will be much appreciated.

Comment: You may have forgot `/` before or after $event->folder. Try to make some debug to display the entire folder name.

Comment: just tried that. `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../registration/' . $event->folder . '/inc/visa_pdf.php');` as well as `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . $event->folder . '/registration/inc/visa_pdf.php');` but didn't work

Comment: When you do a `var_dump(dirname(............);` what is the result?

Comment: domain/admin/ `/ajax/../../registration/americas/_register/inc/visa_pdf.php"` I get this. Does this mean i have to get rid off the /../../ ?

Comment: It looks like your `$event->folder` is wrong then, shouldn't it be `event/folder` instead of `americas/_register` ?

Comment: . $event->folder . this is just a variable that's choosing either event through a variable $event = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); .

Comment: @RomainBar Sir, i fixed it. I concatenated the /registration/ to the string like this: `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../' . '/registration/' . $event->folder . '/inc/visa_pdf.php');`